# Typecasting argv to structure type

Tags: c++, c, unix, linux-kernel

I have a structure defined as

```
struct xyz {

    char *str;
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Which I am getting as input parameter to the executable from some other program1.(other program did `execve` of the `program2` with input parameter as this structure).

I wish to know, can I do the typecast of this input parameter as `(struct xyz*)argv[1];`, or I have to convert it to string format before sending it?

Comment: Stupid question: Did you try ? Did it behaved as expected ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass arbitrary data to a command in that way. You'll have to serialize it to a string, or perform some IPC (e.g. through pipe/socket).

The reason for this is that the strings are null terminated. Your `char*` member will have a `\0` on the end, and even if it doesn't, any int less than 16843009 (`0x01010101`) will have a null byte in it and fail to copy properly.

Comment: Note that integers larger than that number can have null bytes too.

Comment: True. `0x7FFFFF00` will still screw it all up!

Comment: You also need a way to determine where the string in the command line ends and the numbers begin.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - That's what I meant by "serialize it to a string".

Answer (score 0):

argv[1] is a string. You can't cast a string to a struct. You need to create your own wrapper functions to serialize and parse, and then watch out for all sorts of issues -- endian-ness issues and encoding issues (wide chars with Unicode, etc.)